# Get max value from consistent records

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to get max value from given column of consistent data like below :

**id value**

```
1  10 
2  20 
3  30 
4  40
5  50
6  60
7  70
8  80
9  1 
10 2
11 90
12 3
13 110
14 4
```

Output would be 80 .. i dnt have any idea how to attempt it.
your help is appreciable .

Comment: Please define "consistent data"

Comment: Is ID guaranteed to be sequential (no gaps)?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz yes...id will be auto incremented

Comment: If It is populated with multiple statements, In case of a rollback there will be gaps

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT MAX(value) AS MAX FROM table_name;
```

Comment: Is this tested because OP wants 80 not 110

Comment: @gaurav  its not working ..because it will fetch entire column max value not consistent records max value

Answer (score 1):

This solution purely based on your data so for now I am posting this for immediate solution, we can come up with other better ways also:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(t1.val) maxValue
FROM tmp t
INNER JOIN tmp t1 ON t.id+1 = t1.id
WHERE t1.val-t.val = 10
```

Comment: can you please explain it. and why this WHERE t1.val-t.val = 10

Comment: It's just to pick up the consistent data and join with same table to check the first and second row value. It's completely based on your data hope you understand.

Comment: Thanks for yor help ...why this WHERE t1.val-t.val = 10 .....consistent records difference may be vary

Comment: Then do we have any condition based on which we can retrieve the desired output ?

Comment: This solution will work only when id is in increasing order

Comment: Yes, we can have one auto increment column, based on that we can perform the operation and OP want's to get data in the same manner because there is 90 also under value but not considered.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
select id,value from (
  select 
  @last_id as id,  
  @last_value as value,
  case when @last_value is not null 
  then 
    case when @last_value<value 
    THEN
      @counter:=@counter+1
    ELSE
     CASE WHEN @counter!='Change Found' THEN @counter:='Change Found' END
    END
  else -1 
  end as `change`,
  @last_value:=value,
  @last_id:=id
  from Table1,(select @last_value:=null,@counter:=-1,@last_id:=null)p
)tbl where tbl.`change`='Change Found' limit 1;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9dadbc/45)

Answer (score 1):

```
select      value

from       (select      id
                       ,case when value > @prev_value then value end    as value
                       ,@prev_value := value

            from        mytable

            order by    id desc
            ) t

where       value is not null

order by    id

limit       1
;
```

or

```
select      value

from       (select      id
                       ,case when value < @prev_value then @prev_value end  as value
                       ,@prev_value := value

            from        mytable

            order by    id
            ) t

where       value is not null

order by    id

limit       1
;
```

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the chosen solution, I would suggest -

```
select 80;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the HAVING clause like so :

```
select value 
from myTable
GROUP BY value -- forgot this one here
HAVING value = max(value)
```

or i think even a simple of simplest

```
select max(value)
from myTable
```

Comment: Is this tested because OP wants 80 not 110

Comment: I am pretty sure he made a mistake there. He said he wants the max value of the column, so 110 it is

Comment: @MKougiouris  yeah i want max value from consistent records not from entire column....output would be 80 not 110